# Show the maximum height of particle

Tags: projectile-motion

I have the question "A particle is projected so that the horizontal and vertical components of its initial velocity are U and V respectively. Show that the maximum height of the particle is:

V^2 / 2g
"

Here is my attempt however I do not get the correct result what have I done wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the first line?  Where does that equation come from?

Comment: It's the equation used to find the maximum height S as the equation consists of what is needed to find this as it involves V, U and the height S

Comment: The equation $v^2=u^2+2as$ refers to one-dimensional motion in which $u$ is the initial velocity and $v$ is the final velocity.  This is not the case in your problem.  Also, I suspect that $u=v\sin\alpha$ comes from a different interpretation again.  An excellent illustration of the danger of memorising formulae without actually understanding what they mean.

Comment: How is $U$ related to the height?  It's the horizontal component of the initial velocity.

Comment: Yes that's true I've used the wrong equation thanks :)

Comment: But I'm not sure which equation to use ? Because this is the only equation which consists of S, U , V and a

Comment: It's actually the right equation I found the solution online :) thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At maximum height, the vertical velocity is zero. We also know that in simple kinematic situations with constant acceleration:

$$V_f^2 = V_0^2 + 2ax$$

And for our situation, $V_f = 0$, $V_0 = v$, $a = -g$, and $x = h$.

So we have

$$0^2 = v^2 - 2gh$$ Solve for $h$ to get

$$h = \frac{v^2}{2g}$$